# retrieving data from firebase database (localhost) in cloud functions takes too long (sometimes)

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I have 50 000 user in database. I need to query data.(efficiently)
However sometimes it takes too long to load data. Mostly when I do not call functions for longer time. (2 minutes). 
Why is this happening?
How can I improve speed of query?

```
//index.js
exports.userNearBy = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    var time1 = time.time();
    var i = 0;

        admin.database().ref('users/').on('value',function(snapshot){
            snapshot.forEach(function(child){
                i++;
                if(i==49999){
                    console.log(time.time()-time1);
                    response.status(200).send("ok");
                }

            });

});
```

console log
[image]

Comment: I noticed this too with a fairly small database. The calls are much slower than when I used a server.

Comment: yes..on live it takes around 6,7 seconds every call which is not acceptable